# Is it possible to integrate Salesforce Site to Open CTI?

Tags: integration, force.com-sites, cti

I am trying to integrate Salesforce force.com sites to CTI. But I did get any solutions about that.

IS there any way to integrate CTI to salesforce Site ?

Any help is gratefully accepted!

Comment: What do you mean by "integrate CTI to salesforce Site"?

Comment: Yes, I want to integrate CTI to salesforce Site.

Comment: What is the functionality, I mean what is your use case here?

Comment: If any user login in salesforce site. User will able to handle the call and according to the phone number custom Account or lead detail page will open.